# preg_match - Regex to exclude sub directories

Tags: php, regex

I want to display code on the user profile page (user/***uid***)
but exclude the subdirectories / sub-sites. I made a Regex that should return FALSE on following site: user/***uid***/forum_topics , but it does return TRUE. 
(***uid*** = any digit)

My Code with Regex:

```
$regex_profile = '/\buser\/\d*\/?(?!\d)\b/';

if (preg_match($regex_profile, $path))
{
    //Print Activity on User Profile but exclude children
    print render($page['profile_activity_area']); 
}
```

I'm not really skilled with Regex. Hope someone can help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to display the code only on pages that have adress like /user/{ID}

then use simply regex

```
if(preg_match('#\/user\/\d+#', $path)){
  //display code
}
```

regex means that path should have /user/ then digit at least once or more and nothing can be after digit(s).

It will match

- /user/324

but won't match

- /user/234/asdf
- /user/a/asdfa
- /user/234/234234/xzcv/a
- /notuser/234

etc.

Comment: This doesn't work somehow. My path looks like this: _user/1_ and it still displays the code on _user/1/subsite_

`$path = current_path(); // Path: user/<uid>
//Print Activity on User Profile but exclude children
if(preg_match('#user\/\d+#', $path)){
 print render($page['profile_activity_area']); 
}`

Comment: regex is correct if you don't want to display it then use !preg_match I don't know exactly your app logic